# when i wrap stateprovider around a component in reactjs my whole project is not showing in the localhost

Tags: reactjs, redux, firebase-authentication, use-context

```
 <Router>
      <div className='app'>
        <Authprovider>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/posts'>
              <Header />
              <Posts />
              <Footer />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/projects'>
              <Header />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/about'>
              <Header />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/login'>
              <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/signup'>
              <Container
                className='d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'
                style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}
              >
                <div className='w-100' style={{ maxWidth: '400px' }}>
                  <Signup />
                </div>
              </Container>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/'>
              <Header />
              <Main />
              <Footer />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Authprovider>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Container is imported from bootstrap.
Authprovider is the component wrapped around all the components so that I can use the values in all the components

when I wrapped authprovider my screen went blank all the data is dissapeared but i didnt got any error in the console

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { auth } from './firebase'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export const Authprovider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentuser, setcurrentuser] = useState()
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(true)
  const value = {
    currentuser,
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setcurrentuser(user)
      setloading(false)
    })

    unsubscribe()
  }, [])
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

can i know the mistake i had done?

Comment: Your `loading` state has never been set to `false` then ... check out if the callback of `auth.onAuthStateChanged` gets executed

Comment: Right, when `loading` is true you hide all your app UI, including your router and login route, probably not what you wanted to do. Did you really mean to render a loading indicator while loading is true and still render the app?

Comment: I really forgot that one thank you